# UPDATE not working with arrays

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get the info stored in the array updated to the database. I cannot seem to get it to work. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

In the Config Class:

```
function update_cfg(array $upd)
{
    if(is_array($upd))
    {
        $sql = array();
        foreach($upd as $column => $info)
        {
            if(isset($info) && $column != 'update_cfg')
            {
              $sql[] = "`" . $column . "`='" . $info . "'";
            }
        }
        if(is_array($sql))
        {
            $result = $this->Sys->db->query("UPDATE `dj_settings` SET " . implode(', ', $sql));
            if($result)
            {
                unset($sql);
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                unset($sql);
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Script:

```
<?php
global $Sys;

if(isset($_POST['update_cfg']))
{
    unset($_POST['update_cfg']);
    $update = $_POST;
    unset($_POST);
    if($Sys->Config->update_cfg($update))
    {
      $Sys->Template->setAlerts('The website has been successfully updated!');
    }
    else
    {
      $Sys->Template->setAlerts('The website has not been updated.', 'error');
    }
    unset($update);
}

?>
<div id="webCfg">
<h2>Website Configuration</h2>
  <?php

    global $Sys;
    global $handle;

    $alerts = $Sys->Template->getAlerts();
    if ($alerts != '') { echo '<div><ul class="alerts">' . $alerts . '</ul></div>'; }
    asort($handle);
    if($handle['status'] == 1)
    {
        $enable = 'checked="checked"';
    }
    else
    {
        $disable = 'checked="checked"';
    }
    foreach ($handle as $key => $val) 
    {
      $label = str_replace('_', ' ', $key);
      if(strlen($val) <= 50 && !is_numeric($val))
      {
        $input[$key] = '<tr><td class="label"><label for="' . $key . '">' . ucwords($label) . '</label></td><td class="content"><input type="text" id="' . $key . '" name="' . $key . '" value="' . $val . '"/></td></tr>';
      }
      elseif(strlen($val) >= 51 && !is_numeric($val))
      {
        $input[$key] = '<tr><td class="label"><label for="' . $key . '">' . ucwords($label) . '</label></td><td class="content"><textarea id="' . $key . '" name="' . $key . '">' . ucfirst($val) . '</textarea></td></tr>';
      }
      elseif(is_numeric($val))
      {
        $input[$key] = '<tr><td class="label"><label for="' . $key . '">Website Status</label></td><td class="content"><input type="radio" id="' . $key . '" name="' . $key . '" value="1" ' . $enable . '> Enable  <input type="radio" id="' . $key . '" name="' . $key . '" value="0" ' . $disable . '> Disable </td></tr>';
      }
    }
  ?>
  <form action="" method="post">
  <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" id="webCfgTbl">
    <?php
      foreach (array_keys($input) as $key) 
      {
        echo '<div class="row">' . $input[$key] . '</div>';
      }
    ?>
    <tr><td class="label"><label for="submit"></label></td><td class="content"><div class="row submitrow"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="update_cfg" class="submit" value="Update Settings" /></div></td></tr>
  </table>
  </form>     
</div>

?>
```

The info from the database is loaded when the page is. When I change the values and click Update Settings, `$Sys->Config->update_cfg()` returns `FALSE` everytime. I am stumped on this and would appreciate any help. Thanks.

***EDIT***

When I echo the query in the update_cfg() function after the foreach() loop I get this:

```
UPDATE `dj_settings` SET `status`='0', `disabled_msg`=':: Test Message for Disabled Website ::', `email_auto_response`='Thank you so much for your email. I will respond back as soon as I am able. Usually within 30 minutes. Please feel free to look at the pictures and videos on our website, and the FAQ and Pricing tab is a great resource also. I will respond personally to any questions you may have shortly. Have a great day! Some tips on picking the right DJ: For most hiring a DJ is a first time experience. Picking the right DJ can be daunting and sometimes overwhelming task. Here are some good tips to follow to help you through your process. 1. Make sure they have their LLC or INC, and have a business license for your area. 2. Make sure they are insured. 3. Make sure that you sign some kind of a contract throughout the booking process. 4. Check reviews on reputable websites. ie.. thumbtack.com , weddingwire.com, or yellowpages.com. 5. If the price is too good to be true, it is. This is a big one, because you definitely get what you pay for when you hire a DJ. 6. Sit down with a couple of DJ's and talk them, generally your own intuition will get you far. If you follow those steps, you're sure to get a good DJ. No matter who it is, with my company or with a competitor. Your event will go off smoothly 99% of the time. Marshall Bracewell-Owner Dynamic DJ Company, LLC 803-807-1243 http://www.dynamicdjcompany.com', `web_url`='http://www.dynamicdjcompany.com', `web_email`='marshall@dynamicdjcompany.com'
```

Comment: Does it update the database correctly and return `false` or does it not update the database and return false? a

Comment: Have you tried `print_r("UPDATE \`dj_settings\` SET " . implode(', ', $sql));`?

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($this->Sys->db);` to see that the db is working at this point?

Comment: Yes the database is working. No it doesn't update it at all. I have it set to an error page is the db gets no connection. I have printed out the sql query everything seems correct. There is only 1 row in dj_settings so I am trying to update 1 row.

Comment: do you get any mysql errors?

Comment: No errors. Other database functions are working fine.

Comment: If there is only one row, have you tried manually adding in a `where whatever = 'whatever'` to see if that works?

Comment: I am using arrays because if I add a column I don't have to change any code. It will automatically pick up the new column and add it to the array being updated if that makes sense.

Comment: You have a quote in your key `2` => `... DJ's..` that probably messes up your statement.

Comment: I have tried "UPDATE dj_settings SET " . implode(', ' $sql) . " WHERE id = 1". Still doesn't work.

Comment: there is a 2 because i used print_r(). The numbers aren't in the sql, The "columnName" = "INFO" is saved in the sql array. So only the value is imploded in the SQL statement.

Comment: I am just referencing key 2, that value has 2 `'` in the text. You probably have to escape those quotes

Comment: `DJ's` and `you're` probably need be escaped or your sql statement may be invalid.

Comment: So should be `DJ\'s` and `you\'re`

Comment: is there a function that does that? im also using single quotes around the $info in the array. I have editted the last part. I echoed the query instead of print_r on the array.

Comment: Yeah I think `mysqli_real_escape_string()` something like that. I use PDO so I am not 100% up to speed on mysqli, but I know previous mysql had the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function which would turn `'` into `\'`

Comment: The single quotes around the $info is correct, you don't escape those, just any quotes that are contained in the `$info` variable

Comment: yeah trying to figure out how to do that with the values in the array.

Comment: so would be something like: `$sql[] = "\`" . $column . "\`='" . $this->Sys->db->real_escape_string($info) . "'";` I think.

Comment: I used phpmyadmin and inserted my query and this is what i got: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's and talk them, generally your own intuition will get you far. If you follow th' at line 1

Comment: Yeah, you should have received that error, I think you didn't know where to look when I asked previously if you got any mysql errors. To get that error you should have echod `$this->Sys->db->error;` (according to the manual, anyway): http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: This is the error i get when i do that: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' disabled_msg = , email_auto_response = , web_url = , web_email =' at line 1

Comment: Doing this: `$sql[] = "\`" . $column . "\`='" . $this->Sys->db->real_escape_string($info) . "'";` you get that error?

Comment: No it updated but no info was inserted it was actually deleted from the row in the database.

Comment: Well...that's a start I guess...at least the update is working. Try first doing `$info =  $this->Sys->db->real_escape_string($info);` then putting that into the `"\`" . $column . "\`='" . $info . "'";`

Comment: ok that worked. Its working now but the old info from $handle (sets columns in dj_settings as the keys and the info as the value in the $handle array.)  is still being put into the form instead of the updated info from the database. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The database is updating properly. I learned something new. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Well...that's a start I guess...at least the update is working. Try first doing `$info = $this->Sys->db->real_escape_string($info);` then putting that into the `"" . $column . "='" . $info . "'";`